# How does one actually determine if a sequence is exchangeable

Tags: mathematical-statistics, assumptions, intuition, exchangeability

Pardon me if the question is stupid, but I don't understand *how* you go about proving exchangeability of a random sequence. In the case of a distribution such as the normal distribution, I get that since it is determined by the moments, it is all about checking if the moments and covariances are "exchangeable". However, I get stumped at a different example.

Assume we have a infinite sequence of binary random variables which we know are identically distributed, but not indepedent. How do we determine if the sequence is exchangeable (in the sense given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables) ? If I were to guess, I would say that it is something about the covariance, but I am not sure. In practice I feel like it is not feasible to check the joint distribution...

Comment: Usually, this is not "determined" but is *assumed.*  There is no mathematical way to resolve your question unless additional information is supplied about that infinite sequence of variables.

Comment: I mean, that is kind of my question. What information about the ffds needs to be supplied to be able to make that conclusion?

Comment: What are the "ffds"?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344794/exchangeability-and-iid-random-variables/344830#344830

Answer (score 2):

Exchangeability is really a **modeling assumption** and not something you can test for empirically. Some aspects of it can be tested in some settings, but not more. So to make your Q meaningful, we must take it as asking what does this modeling assumption really imply.

Exchangeability is a form of **symmetry**, basically the symmetry that **the ordering of the sample is not informative**. So it excludes things like time series ... see [Independence of events in real-life data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384965/independence-of-events-in-real-life-data?rq=1).  So, a simple random sample is (finitely) exchangeable.  More information can be found at [Exchangeability and IID random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344794/exchangeability-and-iid-random-variables/344830#344830),  [What is the intuition behind exchangeable samples under the null hypothesis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76442/what-is-the-intuition-behind-exchangeable-samples-under-the-null-hypothesis)  and search this site.